# Disproving asymptotic lower bound of central binomial coefficient

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

This is sort of a cross-post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972918/disproving-asymptotic-lower-bound-of-central-binomial-coefficient), since I'm looking for a more mathematical proof.

I was recently learning about binomial coefficients and was wondering about how to disprove 2nCn (or the central binomial coefficient) not being lower-bounded by 4^n; in other words:

$$\binom{2n}{n} \notin \Omega (4^n)$$

Some extremely generous bounds can be easily constructed, such as the following:

$$\frac{4^n}{2n+1} \leq \binom{2n}{n} \leq 4^n \text{ for all } n \geq 1$$

I sought to prove by contradiction, so to assume:

$$\exists c_1 \text{ or } c_2 : 0 \lt c_14^n \leq \frac{4^n}{2n+1} \leq c_24^n \leq \binom{2n}{n} \leq 4^n$$

Clearly, $c_1$ cannot exist, since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2n + 1}} = 0$. It can also be seen that $c_2 \in (0,1]$. And... I'm stuck. Intuitively, it seems rather obvious that $c_2$ cannot exist.

I am aware a similar question has been asked here, but there wasn't really a proof provided. I'm also aware that you could prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n} = 0$, but I was wondering if there was another way to do so - particularly, by proving that $c_2$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction on $n\geq 1$ that $\binom{2n}{n} \leq \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}.$